# Add Firestore document property to subcollection in Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firestore document of job with one of the properties being `jobNumber`. Then I have a subcollection for each test carried out belonging to a particular job. How can I have a Cloud Function that adds the `jobNumber` (property of the document) to a subcollection item once it is added?

Comment: The description you're giving is kind of vague.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know where to start. I want to add a document property (parent) to a sub collection item once the sub collection item is added. Still looking at their documentation.

Comment: I'd start with the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events